# AVD won't stop shutting down

Tags: java, android

I accidently held the power button in MyAVD for too long and it started to shut down, and now it won't stop. I've restarted my computer, closed my IDE, re-ran my code, and it always shows up like so;

[image: Shutting down]

In Logcat it shows:

```
12-16 20:37:19.402: ERROR/DropBoxManagerService(284): Can't write: system_app_strictmode
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/dropbox/drop171.tmp: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
    at com.android.server.DropBoxManagerService.add(DropBoxManagerService.java:210)
    at android.os.DropBoxManager.addText(DropBoxManager.java:272)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$11.run(ActivityManagerService.java:8339)
    Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:400)
    ... 5 more
12-16 20:37:19.441: WARN/Trace(284): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-16 20:37:19.441: WARN/Trace(284): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
12-16 20:37:19.441: INFO/Choreographer(284): Skipped 51 frames!  The application may   be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-16 20:37:19.441: WARN/Trace(284): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
```

Anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: i guess the easiest way would be to recreate the avd

Comment: Try by checking `Wipe User Data` while starting AVD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your AVD manager, select your emulator and go into Edit..., then uncheck "Snapshot" and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Just create new Virtual device, you will save your time and health.